# Speculative History Discussion

Tags: discussion

So this is a chatroom I created a while ago about "what would hve happened if something happened differently"-type stuff. It's on the History community, but it could be useful for worldbuilding. When I hd this chatroom, we were mostly talking about stuff not related to speculative history, so I want to improve on that.

Here's the link. https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117724/speculative-history-discussion

(I don't know if advertisement-style posts are allowed, but I'm willing to learn.)

Comment: Looks like it could be a useful cross-discipline hangout.

Comment: I appreciate the link! You may also want to add it in an appropriate section of our [worldbuilding resources](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/143606/40609) question Q&A. It's too bad SE isn't designed to better accommodate cross-Stack interaction. Thanks for sharing!